# Good design pattern for setting Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

In VBA I have set Application.ScreenUpdating and other application settings using the following class:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ae = Chr(228)
    ao = Chr(229)
    oe = Chr(246)
    aeCap = Chr(196)
    aoCap = Chr(197)
    oeCap = Chr(214)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have implemented it into each entry point into my code with:

```
Sub GetFilePathButton()
    Dim runState As New cRunState
    Set runState = New cRunState

    'My Other Code
End Sub
```

I was very happy with this. Application.ScreenUpdating were taken care of. I didn't need to think about what would happen when errors were thrown or when one function called another. At the end of things the class entrypoint procedure would come to an end an the application settings would reset.

I have tried using the same design pattern in VB.NET

```
Public Class mApplicationSettings
    Dim ExlApp As Excel.Application = CType(AddinModule.CurrentInstance, MyProject.AddinModule).ExcelApp.Application
    Dim ScreenUpdating As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        ScreenUpdating = ExlApp.ScreenUpdating
        ExlApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
        ExlApp.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
    End Sub
End Class
```

And calling it in functions with:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim appSet mApplicationSettings = mApplicationSettings
    'My Other Code
End Sub
```

This doesn't work very well. Sub New() is called and works just fine. But Sub Finalize() never runs. So the application settings never reset.

I have two questions related to this:

- Do you think is a good design pattern good for handling Excel's application settings?
- I haven't gotten it to work as I have described. Can you show me what's wrong or recommend a better design pattern?

Comment: It is a good design pattern for VBA. Not so much for VB.Net since you don't know when (or if) finalizers are called. You need to restore screenupdating manually just before the `End Sub`. Search for try..finally or dispose pattern

Comment: In VBA, screenupdating isn't persistent - when VBA execution ends, screenupdating is always set back to True.  Don't know if that's the case when using VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that implements IDisposable.

In the new method, put the stuff to happen when the object is constructed.

In the dispose method, put the stuff to happen at the end of the using statement.

```
Public Class DisableScreenUpdating
    Implements IDisposable

    Public Sub New()
        ScreenUpdating = ExlApp.ScreenUpdating
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose()
        ExlApp.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Test()
    Dim appSet mApplicationSettings = mApplicationSettings
    Using New DisableScreenUpdating
        'My Other Code
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an example of using the dispose pattern. (like adrianm mentioned above)